# adding value to hidden column in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to add value to hidden column. But it does not work. Can someone please tell me what I am missing here.

http://live.datatables.net/ijotap/10/edit#javascript,html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        bSortClasses: false, 
        "sRowSelect": "single",
        bFilter: false,
        bLengthChange : false,
        aoColumns: [ 
        /* Name */   null,
        /* IP */  null,
        /* Username */ null ,
        /* Password */  { "bVisible":    false }
        ]
  });
  $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData([ "name", "1.1.1.3", "username", "password" ]);
  var rows = $('#example').dataTable().fnGetNodes();
  for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
    console.log("name=" + $(rows[i]).find("td:eq(0)").html());  
    console.log("ip=" + $(rows[i]).find("td:eq(1)").html());
    console.log("username=" + $(rows[i]).find("td:eq(2)").html());
    console.log("pwd=" + $(rows[i]).find("td:eq(3)").html());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but may be the graphical presentation does not include the hidden TD, so there is only 3 TD and not 4 (check it on firebug).

You should retrieve internal data instead of graphical HTMLElement node.

Try to use the method `fnGetData()`.

Read from the documentation:

"Get the data for the whole table, an individual row or an individual cell based on the provided parameters".

Take a look at http://www.datatables.net/api